# Webresource.axd problem between regular and secure domain paths

Tags: asp.net, iis, path, webresource.axd

In our setup there are two different websites in IIS 7 setup that point to the same physical path. One with the binding http://**websitename**.domain.com/ *(virtual root ~ is /)*

and the second at https://webserver.domain.com/**userid**/**websitename** (*so the virtual root ~ is /userid/websitename)*. We use the second for secure aspects of each website.

This causes a problem with the loading of the Webresources.axd files for generated css, and javascript for the AJAX.net toolkit.

Is there a way to have the path to these generated resource files modified.  Or somehow set the virtual root path per application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one solution, using the Render() method to replace the url paths with the correct one.  This [forum post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1119487/1750443.aspx) has info on this solution.  I'll have to modify it to check the Request.Url to see which domain the page request is coming from.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
     try
     {                  
          StringBuilder renderedOutput = new StringBuilder();    
          StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter(renderedOutput);    
          HtmlTextWriter tWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);    
          base.Render(tWriter);

          //this string is to be searched for src="/" mce_src="/" and replace it with correct src="./" mce_src="./". 

          string s = renderedOutput.ToString();
          s = Regex.Replace(s, "(?<=<img[^>]*)(src=\\\"/)", "src=\"./", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
          s = Regex.Replace(s, "(?<=<script[^>]*)(src=\\\"/)", "src=\"./", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
          s = Regex.Replace(s, "(?<=<a[^>]*)(href=\\\"/)", "href=\"./", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

          writer.Write(s);
      }
      catch
      {
      }
  }
}
```